# How to activate tooltip only for a particular row in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a row which has the total value and I would like the tooltip to work only for that particular row. How can I do that in tableau?

Thank you[image: ![e]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH8s7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. Made use of a floating box to cover the areas where I don't want the tooltip to be shown.